# Are there other Truth Potions besides Veritaserum?

Tags: harry-potter

I guess I'm on a *Goblet of Fire* kick today.

Anyhow, after Dumbledore disarms Crouch/Moody following the third task, Crouch Jr is left unconscious for a while; Dumbledore says this:

> ‘Severus, please **fetch me the strongest Truth Potion you possess**, and then go down to the kitchens, and bring up the house-elf called Winky.
>   Minerva, kindly go down to Hagrid’s house, where you will find a large black dog sitting in the pumpkin patch. Take the dog up to my office, tell him I will be with him shortly, then come back here.’
>   <sub>*Goblet of Fire* - pages 591-592 - Bloomsbury - chapter thirty-five, *Veritaserum*</sub>

Clearly Veritaserum is the strongest Truth Potion Snape has, because that is what he returns with. But does this mean there are other types of Truth Potions that maybe aren't as strong as Veritaserum, or that are more potent? Or is the text merely stating that there are different degrees of Veritaserum itself, and that it's maybe a potion that covers a spectrum of potency?

**Are there other Truth Potions besides Veritaserum?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best evidence I can find for other truth drugs comes from *Fantastic Beasts*, in the entry on the Jobberknoll:

> Jobberknoll feathers are used in Truth Serums and Memory Potions.

If Veritaserum was the only truth potion, then why not mention it by name? Likewise with Dumbledore in the *Goblet of Fire* quote. It suggests to me that there are a whole family of truth drugs, of which Veritaserum might be the strongest or most well-known.

Comment: I don't think it's weak at all. I think it kind of leans toward there being more than one kind of truth potion, and that would be interesting. I may steal your Jobberknoll quote and ask what memory potions do, as I don't recall reading about them in the books, unless it was in *OOTP* in the *Christmas On the Dai Llewelyn Ward* chapter (or some name like that).

Comment: @Slytherincess: I meant weak because it’s only based on conjecture; I’d prefer to have a named example for a “strong” answer. I don’t think there’s any canon info about Memory Potions, beyond the brief mention in the Jobberknoll entry.

Comment: I agree, it's an excellent answer, though I disagree 100% (I think this was JKR being her usual vague unclear self and meaning what the question suggested "the strongest of Veritaserum batches you have"

Comment: @alexwlchan -- I have a running list of HP questions and post them when I have the time, and one of them is specifically about memory charms ... I might see if I can work in the Jobberknoll aspect -- if you don't mind, of course -- in an authentic way. I *am* curious about it ... :)

Comment: @DVK -- That's entirely possible, of course. I think it would be interesting if there were more than one truth potion, but, otoh, why would potioneers develop only semi-potent potions meant to elicit the most guarded of information from someone? :)

Comment: I agree. The fact that it's 'serums' (plural) clearly indicates that there are others, potentially with less side-effects or potency.

Comment: @Slytherincess: They might come up with less potent serums as they experiment towards discovering a perfect truth serum. Not deliberate, but not useless either.

Comment: @Slytherincess I wouldn't disregard the semi-potent potions as they are often easier to make or require different less valuable ingredients much like Love potions there are many different brews to make them but The Weasley twins market there's as the most powerful, Slughorn later confirms it is a very powerful love potion.